# A simple javascript/jQuery minifier in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, compression, minify, on-the-fly

I want to compress my JS and jQuery code using the following method:

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/minifier.php');
header("Content-Type:application/x-javascript");

//here catching and gzip {...]

//This file will be compressed.
ob_start("minifier");
?>

... here a lot of javascript code ...
```

I've tried jsmin https://github.com/rgrove/jsmin-php/, but it's not maintained anymore. I'd prefer something easier... Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [mlitn's package](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7519-PHP-Optimize-JavaScript-and-CSS-files.html) for this kind of task.

Works flawlessly out of the box